# Nexus 6 automatically remounting system read-only, deleted files returning

Tags: adb, shell, twrp, mount, nexus-6

tl;dr

- I mount system `rw`
- I try to copy/update/write `/system/xposed.prop`
- System is auto-remounted `ro`, causing the write to fail (applicable to a variety of workarounds)
- Moving/renaming/deleting files causes them to resurrect after a `umount`/`mount` cycle, but only for some files.

Environment: `TWRP 3.0.0-1 shamu`, using `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32`.

Also attempted with a 2.x version of TWRP and ADB 1.0.31.  Recovery is freshly installed.  Problematic write commands include shell redirection (`>`), `cp`, `mv`.  This is reproducible on my device whether I use `mount`, `/sbin/mount`, or `busybox mount`.

For reference (state of desired file BEFORE update):

```
~ # ls -l /system/xposed.prop
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            65 Feb 29 04:17 /system/xposed.prop
```

From `adb shell`

`/system` appears to be mounted correctly

```
/system # mount
...
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41 on /system type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Some sanity testing

```
/system # touch a
/system # ls a
a
/system # rm a
/system # ls a
ls: a: No such file or directory
```

Ok, copy a file (`xposed.prop`) to `/system`

```
/system # cat /data/media/0/xposed-v80-sdk22-arm/system/xposed.prop > /system/xposed.prop
/system # cat: write error: Read-only file system
```

How peculiar.

```
/system # mount
...
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41 on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Somehow `/system` got remounted `ro`?

```
/system # cd /
~ # mount -o remount,rw /system
~ # mount
...
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41 on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
~ # mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p41 /system
~ # mount
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41 on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Well, remount doesn't seem to work.

From another shell on my workstation {

```
$ adb root
adbd is already running as root
$ adb remount
remount of system failed: Read-only file system
remount of vendor failed: Read-only file system
remount failed
```

}

Helpful.

Back to `adb shell`

```
~ # umount /system
~ # mount
...
~ # mount -o rw /dev/block/mmcblk0p41 /system
~ # mount
...
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41 on /system type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Ok looks remounted. Let's try this again.

```
~ # cat /data/media/0/xposed-v80-sdk22-arm/system/xposed.prop > /system/xposed.prop
cat: write error: Read-only file system
```

... *sigh*

```
~ # umount /system
~ # mount -o rw /system
```

More [in]sanity testing

```
~ # touch system/a
~ # ls -l /system/a
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             0 Feb 29 04:18 /system/a
~ # umount /system && mount -o rw /system
~ # ls -l /system/a
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             0 Feb 29 04:18 /system/a
```

Ok. Let's try going the long way around

```
~ # cat /data/media/0/xposed-v80-sdk22-arm/system/xposed.prop > /system/a
~ # ls -l /system/a
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            40 Feb 29 04:27 /system/a
```

Looks like the data got written.

```
~ # mv /system/a /system/xposed.prop
~ # ls -l /system/a
ls: /system/a: No such file or directory
~ # ls -l /system/xposed.prop
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             0 Feb 29 04:18 xposed.prop
```

0 bytes??

```
~ # umount /system && mount -o rw /system
~ # ls -l /system/a
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             0 Feb 29 04:18 a
~ # ls -l /system/xposed.prop
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            65 Feb 29 04:17 xposed.prop
```

And now my files are zombies, reanimating from the dead.

```
~ # rm /system/a
~ # umount /system && mount -o rw /system
~ # ls -l /system/a
ls: /system/a: No such file or directory
```

Ok, I have no idea what's going on now.

Anyone seen anything like this before?  I'm suspecting some weird kernel stuff is happening, but this should be stock/default Nexus 6 Android kernel.